# LibreOffice - auto Increment by 1 field

Tags: csv, openoffice.org, spreadsheet

I'm using LibreOffice and I would like to have a column that auto increments by one. How can I do that?

Comment: Whoops, meant to vote as off-topic (belongs on http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way around this. It's not making the LibreOffice auto increment by one when you add a record but it gave ma a field with those ID numbers I needed.

I've imported the CSV file form LibreOffice into a MySQL table.

The MySQL table had a field with auto increment by one so when I did the import it incremented the number for every record imported.

Then I exported all the records back onto CSV using MySQL Query Browser so I can use it on my LibreOffice app.

The reason I could not do this by hand is because there were over 40k records and it would have taken forever.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put your starting number in the first field, A1 for example. Then put =A1+1 in the next row at A2. Copy A2 and paste to the rest of the column. A3 automatically becomes =A2+1, A4 becomes =A3+1 so on and so forth.